# Is "God" real from a scientific perspective?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

[Study Maps The Odd Structural Similarities Between The Human Brain And The Universe](https://www.sciencealert.com/wildly-fun-new-paper-compares-the-human-brain-to-the-structure-of-the-universe)

[Are Neural Networks About to Reinvent Physics?](http://m.nautil.us/issue/78/atmospheres/are-neural-networks-about-to-reinvent-physics)

[The world as a neural network](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.01540)

Many other references are available in the same direction.

So there are similarities between the mathematical models governing these two systems,  as related to the the fractal nature of the universe we live in (mathematical  similarities at different scales ). In future studies of these similarities (going beyond structural similarities  and into dynamical similarities )  would it be possible to ascertain some sort of intentionality,  purpose or meaning (in terms of our language, as related to the  notion of consciousnesss  ) related/associated  to the whole universe we live in? Atheists claim that religion is an invention of the human mind. In light of these mathematical similarities (and other future  developments ) could it be the case that "God" (a vaguely defined  concept at this stage of development  from a  [scientific](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) viewpoint ) is as real as the universe itself?

"Reality is that which  , when you stop believing in it , doesn't go away".  Phillip K. Dick.

Mathematical fact is one of those things that don't go away easily.

Comment: Downvoting my question is fine, I couldn't care less, but the purpose of my question is to get an answer from presumably more knowledgeable people than myself. Answer appreciated. I am following the scientific method (hundreds of years old). What guiding principles are you following? (this is a question for the downvoters with no argument )..

Comment: Being God "a vaguely defined concept at this stage of development from a scientific viewpoint", how can anyone discuss its existence or "reality"?

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be a hypothesis to dismiss.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu a) an hypothesis must be objectively and clearly defined, if not, it can't be considered to be scientific. Write it down. b) The reason for your "hypothesis" seems to be the existence of patterns. That is not enough. Most science already accepts their existence a priori. c) You need to include a clear definition of God. It is useless to formulate an hypothesis about something that can't be defined (for now, your question is: "does this thing that I don't understand and and I can't describe, exists, because I see patterns?")

Comment: Yes you're right @RodolfoAP   , this is just seeing some  patterns,  but isn't  this what  discovery is all about (following  the scientific  method,  once again ) ?. It's just statistically improbable that these "patterns"  are happenstance.

Comment: Similar causes tend to give similar results. Many things tend to be round, because circles and spheres have the best "content to frontier" ratio. It's also the shape created by omnidirectional forces in equilibrium. Round stuff are described with Pi, sine and cosine, and that's why those are useful in so many formulas. There is nothing mystical or meaningful here. The similarities between the brain and the universe are superficial at best. "Incredible! They are both made at 70% of... something. Not the same something, mind you. But something. Can't be random. Nope."

Comment: That's a reductionist viewpoint @armand , and I can't disagree with you, that's a fundamental tool in scientific endeavor. The word "Gid" carries a lot of luggage with it, so let me rephrase the question.  Are there any similarities between the large scale structure/dynamics and smell scale structure/dynamics in our  universe  ?

Comment: God is a super-sensual concept. It, She, He, is of a spiritual nature, not material. As such, there is no 'proof' of God in science as science only measures objects within the sensual universe. In short, God is not something that is dealt with in the realm of science

Comment: Keep science and religion apart. Maybe you're right @Vishwananda

Comment: If you can provide a reasonably credible "scientific" answer to the question "Does God exist?" then you will become famous (at least in some circles).

Comment: Fame, fortune,  trinkets for feeble minds. Knowledge,  that's where the treasure is. My question is based on the evidence mentioned in the references.

Comment: In light of the diverse comments and answers, I recommend you revise the question for clarity and precision.

Comment: Question closed , opinion based  ?¿?¿?. What a pity,  some of the answers that I got here contain seeds of really interesting ideas, soon to disappear from sight.  Tough luck.

Comment: "Reality is that which  , when you stop believing in it , doesn't go away".  Phillip K. Dick.

Comment: @swami "God is a super-sensual concept" how retarded are you? If you have no idea what it is at all, then how can you make statements with such certainty like he is "super sensitive concept how do you know He's not material, if you have absolutely y idea in any way whatever in the slightest of what He is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your terms. God like soul, means all kinds things to all kinds people.

Do you mean an interventiinist deity that responds to prayer? It's unlikely anyone can find evidence of that.

Do you mean panentheism, or the god-of-the-philosophers? That is really a matter of redefining terms rather than any assertion of substance.

Cells have gathered together in humans to create something far beyond what any individual cell could. Cities [can be considered as organisms](https://youtu.be/k2i7eGSNaNc). Before the heat death of the universe, might all the matter be drawn into a computation, that impacts the next iteration of the universe? It's possible, and would be a kind of deity. Emergent, rather than imminent, or pre-existing, though.

'All knowing', 'all powerful', are philosophically untenable superlatives though.

The term god comes with so much baggage, and so little clear content, I'd suggest avoiding it, and finding other more specific terms. Note how different the dharmakaya is to any Abrahamic deities.

What is a given definition, and framework, trying to achieve, is typically a  ore important question, especially in a social context which all religiins occur in, rather than focusing on epistemic or ontological claims. I believe the general cynicism your question is recieving, relates to that. If there is a cosmos-spanning mind, it's hard to imagine how it could possibly care what any of us think about it.

Comment: There are many venues that can be pursued,  like Davies' insight  http://m.nautil.us/issue/42/fakes/is-physical-law-an-alien-intelligence or various versions of omega point theories  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_Point#:~:text=The%20Omega%20Point%20is%20the,Chardin%20(1881%E2%80%931955). Personally I don't particularly subscribe to any of these thought processes  , I just want to understand what a higher form of consciousness means. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: And if I was capable of clearly defining all the terms/notions  in my question then I wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: I would be disappointed in a God answering prayers coming from people asking for material things, or an edge in their petty little worlds , but I would bow my head in the presence of a God who is open for information exchange (for lack of a better wording) with the most humble and insignificant entities in the universe living on a remote rock in the middle of nowhere, like us.

Comment: In other words I don't look at prayer as an  ask/receive process but more of  a synchronization process with the soul of the universe we live in.  I know, highly speculative  but I tried to answer your remark from your answer (about prayer).

Comment: And here I look at this synchronization process as talking place beyond the spacetime framework of our best present day mathematical models of the physical universe,  with its relativistic light speed  limitations of  information transfer.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu: what about a participatory deity? Have you encountered the Kurzgesacht video story The Egg? https://youtu.be/h6fcK_fRYaI I feel it's crucial to stay humble, and open. Any deity-like being must be far beyond what we can understand in nature & purposes. Creating something collective between us seems capable of more posituve impacts now than other models, to me.

Answer (score 4):

> "*So there are similarities between the mathematical models governing these two systems*" (namely the brain and the universe)

Both the brain and the universe are physical structures, so there is nothing particularly improbable in the idea that they should share some similarities.

> "*would it be possible ascertain some sort of intentionality, purpose or meaning*"

Why are you asking? It is obviously *always* possible (to) ascertain anything and this without any evidence at all. We see many people doing this all the time.

Take two strings of alphabetical characters. Suppose the first string is the original text of Descartes's Discourse on the Method, certainly one of the most meaningful philosophical texts ever written, and the second one a string with exact same number of characters, but whose characters are randomly determined.

We could compare the two strings, character for character. We would find that many characters occur at the same positions in both strings. We would also find identical substrings occurring  at the same location or at different locations.

Given this, *would it be possible to ascertain some sort of intentionality, purpose or meaning*? No. All we need is to understand probabilities.

Same thing for the structure of the brain versus the structure of the universe. Similarities might be significant in terms of their respective structures and in terms of how these structures evolved, but any notion of *intentionality, purpose or meaning* can only be self-delusion or wishful thinking.

No one dedicated to following the scientific method would assert anything from mere similarities, however striking they may be. Scientists don't *assert*. They observe the universe, conceive of possible theories explaining what they have observed, and they keep observing the universe to try and find new facts that would falsify the theory.

This process requires that the theory in question should be possibly falsified. It is very easy for example to imagine the sort of facts that would falsify the Theory of General Relativity. By contrast, it is completely unclear how you could possibly falsify a notion of *intentionality, purpose or meaning*.

This is no science. No one follows the scientific method who indulges in asserting *intentionality, purpose or meaning* from mere similarities.

Comment: I agree  @Speakipigeon  , your arguments are sound, but make sure you don't throw away the baby wìth the bathwater.  These  mathematical similarities are not meaningless.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu > "*These mathematical similarities are not meaningless.*" -- I'm afraid people tend to confuse the deterministic nature of the reality we all share with it progressing towards a specific outcome. If you want, all things happen *because* of *the* reason, not *for* some reason: "*Through* [*the Lógos*] *all things were made; without it, nothing was made that has been made.*"

Comment: "... *in it was life, and that life was the light of men. And the light shines in the darkness, yet the darkness didn't __comprehend__ it.*" <== cause it's true

Comment: @Speakpigeon > "*Given this, would it be possible to ascertain some sort of intentionality, purpose or meaning? No. All we need is to understand probabilities.*" -- and I absolutely appreciate the gesture, but.... not yet :) In this particular case, all we need to understand is the Theory of Evolution.

Comment: @YuriAlexandrovich May be you have a point, but I don't get it. "*All we need is to understand probabilities*" was in reference to my example with the two strings.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu "*These mathematical similarities are not meaningless*" Where did I say there were?! On the contrary, I said "*Similarities might be significant in terms of their respective structures and in terms of how these structures evolved*".

Comment: ... we do need to understand probabilities, however, *to decide on our faith rationally*. To ensure that even our choice of God as the Ultimate Reality we make just as consciously, just as rationally as we do each and every other choice.... and that's how it should have been, with any luck -- and it has been for 99% of our history as anatomically modern humans, until we ran out of the damn thing just 3000 years ago.

Comment: @Speakpigeon > "*...to understand probabilities" was in reference to my example with the two strings*" -- fair enough. I thought it would pay to clarify that we don't enjoy Cristian's "mathematical similarities" due to a random chance. We had evolved our human Lógos (our individual Souls) to be exact copies of God's own (the divine spirit) <== a metaphor, of course. In tech. speak, we evolved specialized computing hardware (it's in our prefrontal cortex) capable of assembling and running a c̸o̸m̸p̸u̸t̸e̸r mental simulation of the reality we all share -- and of *ourselves* being a part of it.

Comment: That's how we can understand every part of reality -- ourselves, our lives, [how the world goes round](https://youtu.be/xAl1R-gcq4Q): It always starts with "why?...", looking for explanations -- and you won't explain shit to your grandma unless you have a model for it! And you'd better, cause it won't be the last one in need of an explanation -- we need them for ourselves, first and foremost, but the grandma can check your math... also best practices matter... And did I mention models? 'Cause honestly,  grandma is not your problem. Your problem is that you need *more* of them... like ten mo...

Comment: ... re? And not just grandmas, ten times everyone -- siblings, parents (generally speaking), aunts... a 4-year old girl can ask 400 "why's" *a day*, boys in hot pursuit, so in real life, we ask them to can it. But if we didn't, *and* if we knew the answers ourselves *and* could communicate them fast enough... Now it goes beyond simply piling up models -- now we are connecting the dots, piecing up the Big Picture out of individual models, like a jigsaw puzzle. Each time you realize there is a connection, you have the proverbial light bulb going off in your head... Untill you reach....

Comment: ... a critical mass and suddently your world lights up as everything falls into their places, and you can see the big picture... Enlightment is the moment you, as your conscious rational Self becomes a human Soul. That's how you understand God, the by getting your very own, individual copy of the guide to Unltimate Reality.

Comment: My plan all along was to write it down as a book. Let me know if you want a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Any scientific theory will reflect "consciousness" insofar as it is conceivable by and structured out of consciousness. And indeed our own scientific rationality probably owes much to our ancient and ongoing contemplation of shapes, points, and lines in the stars.

In some vague Hegelian-Anthropic sense, we may find that physics, once advanced enough to include explanations of the physicist as well, will appear to have a recursive structure reflecting a similarity to the brains that conceived it. However, this is all pretty fanciful, and we do tend to see "patterns" everywhere we look.

The problem is that from any scientific standpoint, put simply, knowledge advances on the basis of falsifiable hypotheses capable of making predictions. God is not a falsifiable thesis, and *by definition* is unpredictable. A divine will is a free will, unbound by the necessities or laws enabling *scientific* prediction, hence capable of *miraculous* activities.

It is far more probable, I would suggest, that science will *create* the transcendental omniscient, omnipresent judge we have always imagined than discover this mega-subject pre-existing in the fractal structures of matter. But, hey, who knows?

Comment: "....science will create the transcendental....". Interesting,  this is a modern interpretation of "self fulfilled prophecies " , if I understand correctly what you're saying.  As we approach the technological singularity,  this is not impossible,  but I  am still confident that we are way behind what the universe has in store for us.

Comment: In other words the universe has been there (in that particular spacetime threshold point)  many, many, many times before.